# Open two browser in one time Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I got a test framework which works fine but too slow cause it should open a browser and log in into the system each time at the beginning of the test case.
My framework able to test the system located on different URL (MSSQL and Oracle)and for different browsers:

```
...
for (WebDriver driver: Drivers) {
    driver =  seleniumWebDriver.loadDriver(testBrowser);
    helpers = new Helpers(driver);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
        for (String siteURL : siteURLtoRUN) {
            SuiteBase.Add_Log.info("Run test for " + siteURL);
            helpers.getAppbase().loginAndOpenSolution(siteURL, environmentNameArg, solutionNameArg, appNameArg, Param.getProperty("userLogin"), Param.getProperty("userPassword"), menuItemName, Param, helpers, driver);
...
```

I tried to move call for driver, helper and loginAndOpenSolution method to the @BeforeSuite TestNG method but found out new problem -
how to handle multi-URL and multi Driver cause I could not run Mozilla and Chrome browser at one time (I need to test both).

```
...    
seleniumWebDriver = new SeleniumWebDriver();
           //if (!Param.getProperty("parameterTestBrowser")){testBrowser = Param.getProperty("parameterTestBrowser");} else
           if (TestBrowserMozilla != null){
            driverMozilla =  seleniumWebDriver.loadDriver(TestBrowserMozilla);
            driverMozilla.manage().window().maximize();
            Drivers.add(driverMozilla);
           }
           if (TestBrowserChrome != null){
            driverChrome =  seleniumWebDriver.loadDriver(TestBrowserChrome);
            driverChrome.manage().window().maximize();
            Drivers.add(driverChrome);
           }
           if (TestBrowserIE != null){
            driverIE =  seleniumWebDriver.loadDriver(TestBrowserIE);
            driverIE.manage().window().maximize();
            Drivers.add(driverIE);
    }
...
```

Looks like @BeforeSuite is not a cure for my problem.
Are there any best practice here or links or advises? I researched StackOverflow and other sources but found only simple examples where user run browser one by one (as I'm doing right now).

Comment: Is multithreading a suitable option for you? Have a look at this: https://www.browserstack.com/automate/testng#running-parallel-tests. This might help you out.

Comment: Can't you just save cookies after you log in for the first time and load them up before each test?

Comment: Will try to investigate both ways, thank you!